# action SDK not working

Tags: google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I have updated my index.js as below

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin     = require('firebase-admin');
const {actionssdk} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = actionssdk({debug: true});


 exports.dairyProduct = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log("request-------------->",request);
    console.log("response----------------->",response);

    function handleMainIntent(app) {
        console.log("Inside Main Intent");
        app.ask("Main Indent "+app.getRawInput());
     }
    function handleTextIntent() {
        console.log("Inside Main Intent");
        app.tell("First Text Indent");
    }
    let app = new ActionsSdkApp({request, response});
    let actionMap = new Map();
    console.log("app---------->",app);
    actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, handleMainIntent)
    actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.TEXT, handleTextIntent);
    app.ask("This sample application is developing by Thirumani Selvam.M ");
    console.log("actionMap---------->",actionMap);
    app.handleRequest(actionMap);
 });
```

My updated action.json

```
    {
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "fulfillment": {
        "conversationName": "testapp"
      },
      "intent": {
        "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
        "trigger": {
          "queryPatterns": [
            "Talk to Dairy Product"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "conversations": {
    "testapp": {
      "name": "testapp",
      "url": "https://us-central1-samplejs6-id.cloudfunctions.net/dairyProduct",
      "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2,
      "inDialogIntents": [
        {
          "name": "actions.intent.CANCEL"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "locale": "en"
}
```

My package.json code

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^4.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

i have deployed using "firebase deploy --only functions"
I have updated action using "gactions update --action_package action.json --project samplejs6-id"
I have updated test of actions using"gactions test --action_package action.json --project samplejs6-id"

I didn't get errors in firebase logs.
i have updated title and name in gactions as "Dairy team". it is recommending to type "Talk to Dairy team" . If i type "Talk to Dairy team" , i am getting response as "We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."

Please let me know, how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you complete everything in the Overview of your project in the Actions on google website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the "actions-on-google" library version 2, but your code is written using the version 1 objects and functions. There have been some dramatic changes between the two versions. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration) for details how to upgrade to the new version, or change your package.json file to use version 1.